# React: SVG hover color doesn't disappear when setting active unless mouse touches screen

Tags: css, reactjs, hover

I'm use Create React App and have svgs for my social icons.

After clicking an icon, a new tab opens. When the user goes back to the tab with the website, the hover color is still there until the mouse moves on the screen. So if the user goes back to the tab but keeps the mouse in the browser's nav bar you will see the hover color remain. This remains when i use `active` `focus` or `visited` to reset the color before hovering or clicking.

If the user only hovers and stays on the page, then it is fine. It's after the user clicks and returns to the site where the hover color remains.

I'm not sure what causes this. Maybe its because I'm changing the styles in CSS rather than using mouseMove events in react? However, I'm not sure how to do what I'm doing in CSS with React events because I have to set the event on the `a` tag and see the color change reflected on the `path` tag.

Can some one please explain why this happens and the best practice around this?

### css

```
a:hover path {
  fill: #f40ef0;
}

a:active path {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

or instead of active use:

```
a:focus path {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

### js

```
const Github = (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    width="30px"
    height="30px"
    viewBox="0 0 438.549 438.549"
    xmlSpace="preserve"
  >
    <g>
      <path
        id="Github"
        d="M409.132,114.573c-19.608-33.596-46.205-60.194-79.798-79.8C295.736,15.166,259.057,5.365,219.271,5.365   c-39.781,0-76.472,9.804-110.063,29.408c-33.596,19.605-60.192,46.204-79.8,79.8C9.803,148.168,0,184.854,0,224.63   c0,47.78,13.94,90.745,41.827,128.906c27.884,38.164,63.906,64.572,108.063,79.227c5.14,0.954,8.945,0.283,11.419-1.996   c2.475-2.282,3.711-5.14,3.711-8.562c0-0.571-0.049-5.708-0.144-15.417c-0.098-9.709-0.144-18.179-0.144-25.406l-6.567,1.136   c-4.187,0.767-9.469,1.092-15.846,1c-6.374-0.089-12.991-0.757-19.842-1.999c-6.854-1.231-13.229-4.086-19.13-8.559   c-5.898-4.473-10.085-10.328-12.56-17.556l-2.855-6.57c-1.903-4.374-4.899-9.233-8.992-14.559   c-4.093-5.331-8.232-8.945-12.419-10.848l-1.999-1.431c-1.332-0.951-2.568-2.098-3.711-3.429c-1.142-1.331-1.997-2.663-2.568-3.997   c-0.572-1.335-0.098-2.43,1.427-3.289c1.525-0.859,4.281-1.276,8.28-1.276l5.708,0.853c3.807,0.763,8.516,3.042,14.133,6.851   c5.614,3.806,10.229,8.754,13.846,14.842c4.38,7.806,9.657,13.754,15.846,17.847c6.184,4.093,12.419,6.136,18.699,6.136   c6.28,0,11.704-0.476,16.274-1.423c4.565-0.952,8.848-2.383,12.847-4.285c1.713-12.758,6.377-22.559,13.988-29.41   c-10.848-1.14-20.601-2.857-29.264-5.14c-8.658-2.286-17.605-5.996-26.835-11.14c-9.235-5.137-16.896-11.516-22.985-19.126   c-6.09-7.614-11.088-17.61-14.987-29.979c-3.901-12.374-5.852-26.648-5.852-42.826c0-23.035,7.52-42.637,22.557-58.817   c-7.044-17.318-6.379-36.732,1.997-58.24c5.52-1.715,13.706-0.428,24.554,3.853c10.85,4.283,18.794,7.952,23.84,10.994   c5.046,3.041,9.089,5.618,12.135,7.708c17.705-4.947,35.976-7.421,54.818-7.421s37.117,2.474,54.823,7.421l10.849-6.849   c7.419-4.57,16.18-8.758,26.262-12.565c10.088-3.805,17.802-4.853,23.134-3.138c8.562,21.509,9.325,40.922,2.279,58.24   c15.036,16.18,22.559,35.787,22.559,58.817c0,16.178-1.958,30.497-5.853,42.966c-3.9,12.471-8.941,22.457-15.125,29.979   c-6.191,7.521-13.901,13.85-23.131,18.986c-9.232,5.14-18.182,8.85-26.84,11.136c-8.662,2.286-18.415,4.004-29.263,5.146   c9.894,8.562,14.842,22.077,14.842,40.539v60.237c0,3.422,1.19,6.279,3.572,8.562c2.379,2.279,6.136,2.95,11.276,1.995   c44.163-14.653,80.185-41.062,108.068-79.226c27.88-38.161,41.825-81.126,41.825-128.906   C438.536,184.851,428.728,148.168,409.132,114.573z"
        fill="#FFFFFF"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
);

const socialList = [
  {
    href: 'https://github.com/turnipdabeets',
    title: 'See my Github projects',
    icon: Github
  },
  ...
];

const Icon = ({ icon, href, title }) => (
  <a className="social" href={href} title={title} target="_blank">
    {icon}
  </a>
);

const SocialGroup = () => (
  <ul className="socialNav">
    {socialList.map(social => (
      <li key={social.href}>
        <Icon href={social.href} title={social.title} icon={social.icon} />
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

UPDATE: This is only happening on chrome web browsers and safari on iOS 10 (not web)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
a:visited path{
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover path {
  fill: #f40ef0;
}
a:active path {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

So that your visited tags will stay the same color.
Because right now your hover color is the same as the default visited color for most browsers.

Comment: for some reason adding visited also requires the mouse to move onto the screen to switch back to white.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your statement: "When I set a hover color I notice that after clicking and visiting the site the icon links to that the hover color remained." Are you saying that after you clink a link on your page, and then you go back to your page, the color becomes the hover color? Also, why did you change the active color to try to solve it? And why is your mouse off the screen? Sorry I'm just confused right now

Comment: Correct. After clicking an icon, a new tab opens. When the user goes back to the tab with the website, the hover color is still there until the mouse moves on the screen. So if the user goes back to the tab but keeps the mouse in the browser's nav bar you will see the hover color remain.

Comment: Can you post your code on codesandbox and send a link? nvm let me think about it

Comment: Using focus seems to work for me. Did you put your focus block last, and your visited block first?

Comment: order: visited, hover, focus.  The problem with setting focus last is, yes the color returns to normal, but if you try to hover over the icon again then you have to click on the screen to see the hover color when hovering haha

Comment: Why can't you set a mouseover listener on the anchor tag? When it mouses over you add a .hover class, and when it's not on the anchor you remove the .hover class. Then you also have a listener for when your page is not visible, which also removes the .hover class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: This shouldn't affect your css because it's just selecting the path tag inside anything with .hover class